# Symfony2 SwiftMailer don't work

Tags: php, symfony, send, swiftmailer, mailer

I want use SwiftMailer for send and email when finish an insert into database in my action controller but doesn't work..
I use swiftmailer for FOSUserBundle and it's work very well..
This is the config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    port:                 false
    encryption:           ~
    auth_mode:            ~
    spool:
        type:                 file
        path:                 "%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool"
    sender_address:       ~
    antiflood:
    threshold:            99
    sleep:                0
    delivery_address:     ~
    disable_delivery:     ~
    logging:              "%kernel.debug%"

# Routing
    be_simple_i18n_routing: ~

# FOSUserBundle Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User 
profile:
    form:
        type: dt_ec_profile
registration:
    confirmation:
        enabled:    true
    form:
        type: dt_ec_registration
from_email:
    address:        ------@------.com
    sender_name:    ------
service:
    mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
resetting:
    email:
        template: DtEcBundle:User:resetting.email.html.twig
```

This is the code of controller:

```
$container->get('swiftmailer.mailer');

$mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance();
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom('------@-----.com')
        ->setTo('------@-----.com')
        ->setBody('You should see me from the profiler!')
    ;

/*    // Pass a variable name to the send() method
if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
{
  echo "Failures:";
  var_dump($failures);
} */

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

How can i do??

Answer (score 1):

Did you basically try in your controller:

```
/.../

$mailer = $this->get('mailer');

$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
    ->setFrom('------@-----.com')
    ->setTo('------@-----.com')
    ->setBody('You should see me from the profiler!')
;

$mailer->send($message);

/.../
```

Comment: I tried in this way but nothing now i try again but not work.. @scoolnico

Comment: Do you have a specific error message or the mail is only not sending?

Comment: I explain, i have a message chat in my web project and when i send a message , the controller send to destinatary of message an email.. But i don't receive any errors... The mail is only not sending  @scoolnico

Comment: As Julien says, spool could be the reason. Try this command line in your console and tell us if you receive message(s): `php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send `

Comment: Not really optimist with this direction but try `disable_delivery:  false` in your `config.yml`...

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've a spool configuration in your `config.yml`

Try to comment these lines :

```
spool:
    type:                 file
    path:                 "%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool"
```

A spool will stock all your email in your `app/cache/dev/swiftmailer/spool` folder and wait for a command to flush them.

Comment: Nothing.. in this path i don't have files. How can i receive an error messages for understand the sentence of problem?? @scoolnico

Comment: By tailing symfony's logs `tail -f app/logs/dev` if you're on linux or something equivalent on others. Do the same on you nginx/apache `error.log`

Comment: I don't know... @Julien Bourdic i see Symfony log but i don't understand, really..

Comment: Another way to intercept what's happened with mails => In `app/config/config_dev.yml` : `web_profiler: intercept_redirects: true`

Comment: @scoolnico i tried but not good ideas.. not this the problem.. now i try with disable_delivery: false

Comment: Can you give us a pastebin of your last 100 lines of your `app/logs/dev` file took just after the execution of the Action ? And...Are you in dev environement ?